# Encoding issues using tycho surefire plugin

Tags: java, unit-testing, character-encoding, maven-3, tycho-surefire-plugin

I've been turning my head around with this issue and cannot find an explanation for what is happening here.
I'm using tycho surefire plugin to build a set of eclipse plugins and execute some unit tests.
Here's the environment:

```
tycho-surefire-plugin: version 0.19.0 //very old I know, but I'm stuck with legacy code
maven 3.5.2
jdk 8
windows 10
```

I've started with a simple test case to test a method that replaces special characters with their simple version:

```
String input = "á:Á-é:É-í:Í-ó:Ó-ú:Ú-ñ:Ñ  ";
System.out.println("testing input: " + input);
Assert.assertEquals("a A e E i I o O u U n N ",
    Utils.sanitize(input, true));
```

the problem here is that when executing the junit directly on eclipse I get the expected result, so the test passes, but when I execute the tycho build I get:

```
testing input: ?:?-?:?-?:?-?:?-?:?-?:?
Failed tests:   testSanitizeWithSpaces(com.fja.eos.automation.UtilsTest): expected:<[a A e E i I o O u U n N] > but was:<[o o o o o o o o o o o o] >
```

The value for

```
System.out.println("Default charset: " + Charset.defaultCharset());
```

is the same in both scenarios:

```
Default charset: windows-1252
```

my next attempt was to read the input value from a file, controlling the charset using:

```
InputStream is = UtilsTest.class
    .getResourceAsStream("sanitationTestSubjects.xml");
InputSource source = new InputSource(is);
source.setEncoding("ISO-8859-1");
Document doc = builder.parse(is);
```

for the file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<SanitationTestSubjects>
    <Subject input="á:Á-é:É-í:Í-ó:Ó-ú:Ú-ñ:Ñ  " expected="a A e E i I o O u U n N " />
</SanitationTestSubjects>
```

while reading the input like this I got a slightly different result:

```
testing input: á:?-é:É-í:?-ó:?-ú:?-ñ:Ñ
```

but still not correct. If I try to get the escaped input with

```
StringEscapeUtils.escapeJava(elem.getAttribute("input"))
```

I get what it seems to be the correct unicode sequence:

```
Escaped input: \u00E1:\u00C1-\u00E9:\u00C9-\u00ED:\u00CD-\u00F3:\u00D3-\u00FA:\u00DA-\u00F1:\u00D1
```

I've tried setting all character encoding options on the tycho-surefire-plugin without any change on behavior:

```
<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
                <artifactId>tycho-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${tycho-version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <appArgLine>-Dfile.encoding=ISO-8859-1</appArgLine>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <encoding>ISO-8859-1</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

one more test, compiling the files on eclipse and with maven results in binary equal files..

UPDATE:
the encoding of the java file itself was set to cp1252, after changing it to ISO-8859-1 I got the same result as reading the value from a file.. still not there..

I'm really feeling that I'm looking to the wrong side of the problem.
can anyone please help?

Comment: Have you specified different encodings in general maven properites like `project.build.sourceEncoding`? Are these encodings defaulting to system defaults? What are the system default encodings of the jvm running your code when you run from within eclipse and from within tycho build?

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to respond SpaceTrucker. I’ve tried to set general maven encoding with the same value as I had on the other properties “ISO-8859-1”. It seems it has no effect. The default encoding is the same in both scenarios: “windows- something.” (I’ll edit this once I get to the pc again).. :(

Comment: Sorry to say it but using a software of 2013 (tycho-surefire-plugin) is itself a problem.. using also a very old Maven version 3.5.2... ? Migrate the project to recent versions of tools because creating plugins for Eclipse is one thing but the question is: Is your target also that old? For newer versions of Eclipse you should use more recent tools as well...

Comment: Thanks for the feedback khmarbaise. Yes, the plugins are for a katalon based RCP, so I'm afraid there's no escape from that..